# How to use Rs neuralnet package in a Kaggle competition about Titanic

Tags: r, machine-learning, neural-network, kaggle

I am trying to run this code for the Kaggle competition about [Titanic](https://www.kaggle.com/c/titanic) for exercise. Its forfree and a beginner case. I am using the neuralnet package within R in this package.

This is the train data from the website:

```
train <- read.csv("train.csv")
m <- model.matrix(  ~ Survived + Pclass + Sex + Age + SibSp, data =train )
head(m)
```

Here I train the neural network, depending on who survived. I want
to see if I can predict who survived:

```
library(neuralnet)

r <- neuralnet( Survived ~ Pclass + Sexmale + Age + SibSp, 
data=m, hidden=10, threshold=0.01,rep=100)
```

The net is trained. I load the test data and prepare it for test.

```
test=read.csv("test.csv")

m2 <- model.matrix(  ~  Pclass + Sex + Age + SibSp, data = test )
```

The final test for prediction:

```
res= compute(r, m2)
```

First, I do not know many hidden neurons I should take. Sometimes it takes to long, and when I succeed I cannot make the test with the test data because an error occurs which says the two data set are not compatible:

```
res= compute(r, m2)

Error in neurons[[i]] %*% weights[[i]] : non-conformable arguments
```

What am I doing wrong here?

The whole code:

```
train <- read.csv("train.csv")
m <- model.matrix(  ~ Survived + Pclass + Sex + Age + SibSp, data =train )
head(m)

library(neuralnet)

r <- neuralnet( Survived ~ Pclass + Sexmale + Age + SibSp, 
data=m, hidden=10, threshold=0.01,rep=100)

test=read.csv("test.csv")

m2 <- model.matrix(  ~  Pclass + Sex + Age + SibSp, data = test )

res= compute(r, m2)
```

Comment: Can you provide everything in one code? For example use comments by comment marks if you need them. Now, it is little difficult to follow your ocde.

Comment: @Masi Added everything in one code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using this to predict instead:

```
res = compute(r, m2[,c("Pclass", "Sexmale", "Age", "SibSp")])
```

That worked for me and you should get some output.

What appears to have happend: `model.matrix` creates additional columns (`(Intercept)`) which isn't part of the data which was used to build the neural net, as such in the `compute` function it doesn't know what do with it. So the solution is to select explicitly the columns needed to use in the compute function. This is because `neuralnet` tries to do some kind of matrix multiplication, but the matrix is of the wrong size.

---

For how many neurons, or optimizing hyper-parameters, you could use Cross-validation and all those other methods. If using a different package (`nnet`) is fine then you can use the `caret` package to determine the optimal parameters for you. It would look like this:

```
library(caret)
nnet.model <- train(Survived ~ Pclass + Sex + Age + SibSp, 
                    data=train, method="nnet")
plot(nnet.model)
res2 = predict(nnet.model, newdata=test)
```

with the plot of the hyperparameters being this:

[image]

---

You can measure performance using the `confusionMatrix` in the `caret` package:

```
library(neuralnet)
library(caret)
library(dplyr)
train <- read.csv("train.csv")
m <- model.matrix(  ~ Survived + Pclass + Sex + Age + SibSp, data =train )

r <- neuralnet( Survived ~ Pclass + Sexmale + Age + SibSp, 
                data=m, rep=20)

res = neuralnet::compute(r, m[,c("Pclass", "Sexmale", "Age", "SibSp")])
pred_train = round(res$net.result)

# filter only with the ones with a survival prediction, not all records
# were predicted for some reason;
pred_rowid <- as.numeric(row.names(pred_train))
train_survived <- train %>% filter(row_number(Survived) %in% pred_rowid) %>% select(Survived)
confusionMatrix(as.factor(train_survived$Survived), as.factor(pred_train))
```

Output:

```
Confusion Matrix and Statistics

          Reference
Prediction   0   1
         0 308 128
         1 164 114

               Accuracy : 0.5910364             
                 95% CI : (0.5539594, 0.6273581)
    No Information Rate : 0.6610644             
    P-Value [Acc > NIR] : 0.99995895            

                  Kappa : 0.119293              
 Mcnemar's Test P-Value : 0.04053844            

            Sensitivity : 0.6525424             
            Specificity : 0.4710744             
         Pos Pred Value : 0.7064220             
         Neg Pred Value : 0.4100719             
             Prevalence : 0.6610644             
         Detection Rate : 0.4313725             
   Detection Prevalence : 0.6106443             
      Balanced Accuracy : 0.5618084             

       'Positive' Class : 0
```

Comment: Thanks!

I have another question about using neuralnet. How do you interpret the results? How can I see if the prediction was accurate?

Comment: see my edit, you can use the caret package with the confusionMatrix function to measure performance.

Comment: Thank you a lot!

But, I have to ask, how did you learn all of this? Any advice? Book recommendation?

Comment: I'm a statistician by trade. I don't really have any recommendations, since the internet probably has everything you can imagine. Sorry I don't really have any helpful advice; for myself it is trying to understand everything from the most basic building blocks and building up your knowledge in that way.